# Applications of semigroups

Tags: reference-request, semigroups-and-monoids

I am limitedly aware of some works done in connecting semigroups and computer sciences. And, indeed, there are many works in this area.

> May I ask you what would the ingeniously work be with this goal?

I am asking here because the giants may want to pay an attention to my little request. :-)

Comment: Try https://www.irif.fr/~jep/PDF/MPRI/MPRI.pdf

Comment: See https://www.math.cornell.edu/~kbrown/scan/2000.0013.pdf for interesting applications in probability.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: Thanks for your time. The first one is really  as I requested.

Comment: certain infinite-dimensional dynamical systems (caucy PDEs..) can be posed as ODEs in Banach space, and studied via semigroup theory. http://bookstore.ams.org/surv-70

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: How can I reach you? I had a presentation and I made a very simple remark about sigma-reflexive semigroup there. One of the audience pointed another proof for the remark suddenly. If I have permission and you have time, I will inform you the case. I will send you my way and will tell you his way. I cannot get his method. Thanks

Comment: You can send me an email at my university email and I'll try and respond in a timely fashion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a question of mine along similar lines:

[Have semigroups with actions on themselves that have a dual to the compatibility axiom ever been studied?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/243022/have-semigroups-with-actions-on-themselves-that-have-a-dual-to-the-compatibility/243106#243106)

The answer by Joseph Van Name may contain something of interest to you, in particular there is a reference given at the end of it.

The question is precisely about the links between semigroup theory and computer science, specifically rewriting theory, funnily enough.